# pIRCbot won't join Twitch channel or send messages

Tags: java, sockets, bots, irc, twitch

The following code connects to Twitch's IRC successfully and triggers the onConnect method which is where everything stops. 
Because pIRCbot has verbose enabled I can see that it does send `JOIN #twitchplayspokemon` after connecting but the specification says that I should get an immediate response with the same text followed by a list of users (which would trigger the onJoin and onUserList methods) which doesn't happen.

I have also tried connecting to my channel and sending a message with
`joinChannel("#[mychannelname]");
sendMessage("#[mychannelname]", "Hello World");`
All this does is send two JOIN commands and doesn't ever join nor message appear in chat.

The tutorial/reference I'm using is http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc

Other responses are also not being output. I am getting the MOTD but not seeing the "End of /MOTD command".

```
import org.jibble.pircbot.*;

public class MyBotMain extends PircBot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MyBotMain bot = new MyBotMain();

        bot.setVerbose(true);

        bot.setName("[myname]");
        bot.setLogin("[myname]");

        try {
            bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv", 6667, "oauth:db4aai4mh474ikbgzzuh76fv67n"); // Not the key I'm using
        } catch (NickAlreadyInUseException e) {
            System.err.println("Nickname is currently in use");
        } catch (IrcException e) {
            System.err.println("Server did not accept connection");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onConnect() {
        System.out.println("Connected!");
        joinChannel("#witchplayspokemon");
        super.onConnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onJoin(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname) {
        System.out.println(login + " joined channel " + channel);
        super.onJoin(channel, sender, login, hostname);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUserList(String channel, User[] users) {
        for (User user : users) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
        super.onUserList(channel, users);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine, the only problem is that the channel you are trying to join is "witchplayspokemon" instead of "twitchplayspokemon" the onUserList(String channel, User[] users) is only giving me one user, But I have been having that problem recently on my own Bot So I am not yet sure on the cause.

Comment: I just read that for e3 twitch has disabled the user list/ join parts of the their IRC chat servers, so onUserList(String channel, User[] users) will not work until they add it back in.